# QGIS Plugin Midvatten error

Tags: midvatten

I am trying to install the midvatten plugin, and the following error is given:

[image]

QGIS version is 2.18, running on Ubuntu 18.04 LTS.
Has anyone come across this error or has any suggestions?

Comment: Wich is your plugin repository? In _Plugins Settings_.

Comment: It may be due to some previous incomplete install/update of the plugin. Perhaps you could try to:
(1) shutdown qgis, 
(2) manually remove the complete midvatten-folder found here ~/.qgis2/python/plugins/
and (3) restart qgis, verify repos as per @GabrielDeLuca's suggestion and make a fresh install of the plugin